# Sql profiler-query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiler

I would like to know regarding performance of two queries. A page is showing 18 records per page. It is implemented in two ways in two different applications, but using same tables and join.

When compared their query in SQL query profiler,

1. The first query fetches all 1 to 18 records and display. It is reading 1.2 million records.
2. The second query fetches 6 records at a time and display, On browser its showing 18 records. It is reading is less than 250k records.

Using almost same join in both queries.

1. Is it possible to show 18 records per page pagination in batches of query? If yes, how it is implemented?
2. Is there another way to find how many records read in an SQL execution other than profiler?

Comment: You need to show us the queries and executions plans for us to be able to sensible comment.

Comment: If your query doesn't use user defined functions or anything like that, just use `set statistics io on` -- but for something complex, you should look at plan cache, `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` or `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`

Answer (score 0):

You can use OFFSET and FETCH to paginate.  See

https://www.sqlshack.com/pagination-in-sql-server/

If you have the queries, you can run it in SSMS to get the execution plans. There will be estimated and actual row count information.

https://www.sqlshack.com/execution-plans-in-sql-server/